# OpenCart - MySQL Error while Adding New Module

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

OpenCart 1.5.6, Default theme.

I've created a new module named 'seller' cloned by 'manufacturer'. Seller module is working okay at Admin side, means adding/editing Seller's details; and linking with individual product is working fine. But when I call it at front-end, product page is giving me an error. I'm not okay with MySQL syntax and may be added wrong syntax. Here are the changes done in file name: \catalog\model\catalog\product.php

Old syntax:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, s.name AS seller, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");
```

and new (changed) to, basically copied manufacturer code and 'added+replaced' to seller:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, s.name AS seller, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "seller s ON (p.seller_id = s.seller_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");
```

Added following code:

```
'seller_id'  => $query->row['seller_id'],
'seller'     => $query->row['seller'],
```

after this code:

```
'manufacturer_id'  => $query->row['manufacturer_id'],
'manufacturer'     => $query->row['manufacturer'],
```

also added following code:

```
if (!empty($data['filter_seller_id'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.seller_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_seller_id'] . "'";
    }
```

after

```
if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";
    }
```

and at last added following code:

```
if (!empty($data['filter_seller_id'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.seller_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_seller_id'] . "'";
    }
```

after:

```
if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";
    }
```

Now, I'm getting following error while I try to open any product page:

```
Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '43' AND pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND p2s.store_id = '0'' at line 3
Error No: 1064
SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, s.name AS seller, m.name AS manufacturer, m.image AS man_img, (SELECT price FROM product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT points FROM product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '1') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '1') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '1') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '1') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM product p LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '43' AND pd.language_id = 'seller s ON (p.seller_id = s.seller_id) WHERE p.product_id = '43' AND pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND p2s.store_id = '0' in /x/x/x/x/system/database/mysql.php on line 50
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Weel took me sometime to rearenge your final sql code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a concatenation problem after rearange your sql code there is a peace that have two where clauses. Hint ALWAYS indent your code it will be a lot easier to find theese mistakes.

this is the part that is wrong:

```
     ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) 
WHERE p.product_id = '43' 
  AND pd.language_id = 'seller s ON (p.seller_id = s.seller_id) 
WHERE p.product_id = '43' 
  AND pd.language_id = '1' 
  AND p.status = '1' 
  AND p2s.store_id = '0'
```

This is entire sql formatted.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, 
p.image, s.name AS seller, 
m.name AS manufacturer, m.image AS man_img, 
(SELECT price 
   FROM product_discount pd2 
  WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND pd2.quantity = '1' 
    AND (     (pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW() ) 
          AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())
        ) 
  ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, 
           pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, 
(SELECT price 
   FROM product_special ps 
  WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND (     (ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) 
          AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())
        ) 
   ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, 
            ps.price ASC LIMIT 1
) AS special, 
(SELECT points 
   FROM product_reward pr 
  WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND customer_group_id = '1') AS reward, 
(SELECT ss.name 
   FROM stock_status ss 
  WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id 
    AND ss.language_id = '1') AS stock_status, 
(SELECT wcd.unit 
   FROM weight_class_description wcd 
  WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id 
    AND wcd.language_id = '1') AS weight_class, 
(SELECT lcd.unit 
   FROM length_class_description lcd 
  WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id 
    AND lcd.language_id = '1') AS length_class, 
(SELECT AVG(rating) AS total 
   FROM review r1 
  WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND r1.status = '1' 
  GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
   FROM review r2 
  WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND r2.status = '1' 
  GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, 
   p.sort_order 
FROM product p LEFT JOIN product_description pd 
     ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
     LEFT JOIN product_to_store p2s 
     ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
     LEFT JOIN manufacturer m 
     ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) 
WHERE p.product_id = '43' 
  AND pd.language_id = 'seller s ON (p.seller_id = s.seller_id) 
WHERE p.product_id = '43' 
  AND pd.language_id = '1' 
  AND p.status = '1' 
  AND p2s.store_id = '0'
```

Comment: That's right. You have suggested right way to detect the problem. :)

Comment: *Hint ALWAYS indent your code it will be a lot easier to find these mistakes.* - You should really look into the OpenCart's model classes, where all of the queries are nicely written in one line... Sometimes a real headache when You need to debug and/or develop something new...

Comment: Hi @shadyyx i'm not sure if I understand your comment. Are you saying that it is better to have a huge query like that on the OPs question in just one line? I'm sorry if I missundestood you.

Comment: Yep, You completely misunderstood :-) I mean it is of course better to have the query nicely formatted, but in OpenCart, all of the SQL queries are written in one line (so the query that's in OP's question is just a copy from OpenCart, not his work). And that it is often a headache to debug or develop with such a huge queries written in one line...

Comment: @shadyyx Oooh "it is sarcarsm Sheldon!" hahahahahahaha sorry for that. My english is not soo good, I'm still learning how to understand some ways of interpret phrases :)